# Problems using Cython and multiprocessing

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, multiprocessing, cython

I am having trouble while trying to use two Cython compiled modules (`Fibril(...)` and `GetIntersect(...)`). The specific behaviour seems to change upon every computer restart but, along with filling my hard drive space, the multiple printing of the line `imports loaded` seems to be reproducible.
This is the full code for the script I'm running :

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import multiprocessing
import copy
import Fibril
import GetIntersect

print("imports loaded")
N_p = 40
N_t = 30000
dt = 5e-9
D_0 = 2.3e-3
dr = np.sqrt(6 * D_0 * dt) 
L_0 = 1e-4
T = []
for i in range(0, 17):
    T.append(i * 0.1)
T.append(193 / 120)
Phis = []
D_1 = []
D_23 = []
def ComputePhi(T, points):
    accepted = 0
    for i in range(int(-points / 2), int(points / 2)):
        for j in range(int(-points / 2), int(points / 2)):
            if Fibril(i * 1e-7, j * 1e-7, L_0) > T:
                accepted += 1
    return accepted / ((2 * int(points / 2)) ** 2)

def Boost(coordinates, dr):
    theta = 2 * np.pi * (np.random.uniform())
    phi = np.arccos(2 * np.random.uniform() - 1)
    coordinates[0] += dr * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
    coordinates[1] += dr * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
    coordinates[2] += dr * np.cos(phi)
    return phi, theta

def GetDTensorElementAddend(coordinateshistory, i, j):
    return (coordinateshistory[1][i] - coordinateshistory[0][i]) * (
        coordinateshistory[1][j] - coordinateshistory[0][j]
    )

def SimulParticle(particle_index, N_t, N_p, dt, dr, L_0, T):
    np.random.seed()
    coordinates = [
        np.random.uniform(0, L_0),
        np.random.uniform(0, L_0),
        np.random.uniform(0, L_0),
    ]
    while Fibril.Fibril(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], L_0) - T > 0:
        coordinates = [
            np.random.uniform(0, L_0),
            np.random.uniform(0, L_0),
            np.random.uniform(0, L_0),
        ]
    coordinateshistory = [[coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2]], []]
    for i in range(0, N_t):
        oldcoord = copy.copy(coordinates)
        phi, theta = Boost(coordinates, dr)
        bordercrossing = Fibril.Fibril(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], L_0)
        if bordercrossing - T > 0 and oldcoord[1] != coordinates[1]:
            m = (coordinates[1] - oldcoord[1]) / (coordinates[0] - oldcoord[0])
            q = coordinates[1] - m * coordinates[0]
            coordinates[0], coordinates[1] = GetIntersect.GetIntersect(
                coordinates, oldcoord, m, q, T, L_0
            )
            coordinates[2] = coordinates[0] / (np.tan(phi) * np.cos(theta))
    coordinateshistory[1] = [coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2]]
    D_xx = GetDTensorElementAddend(coordinateshistory, 0, 0) / (2 * N_t * dt * N_p)
    D_xy = GetDTensorElementAddend(coordinateshistory, 0, 1) / (2 * N_t * dt * N_p)
    D_xz = GetDTensorElementAddend(coordinateshistory, 0, 2) / (2 * N_t * dt * N_p)
    D_yy = GetDTensorElementAddend(coordinateshistory, 1, 1) / (2 * N_t * dt * N_p)
    D_yz = GetDTensorElementAddend(coordinateshistory, 1, 2) / (2 * N_t * dt * N_p)
    D_zz = GetDTensorElementAddend(coordinateshistory, 2, 2) / (2 * N_t * dt * N_p)
    return [[D_xx, D_xy, D_xz], [D_xy, D_yy, D_yz], [D_xz, D_yz, D_zz]]


def MainLoop(N_t, N_p, dt, dr, L_0, T):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)  # Create a pool of worker processes
    results = []
    for i in range(N_p):
        result = pool.apply_async(SimulParticle, args=(i, N_t, N_p, dt, dr, L_0, T))
        results.append(result)
    particle_results = [result.get() for result in results]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return particle_results


# simulation start
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for t in T:
        DT = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
        sim_results = MainLoop(N_t, N_p, dt, dr, L_0, t)
        for result in sim_results:
            DT = [
                [DT[i][j] + result[i][j] for j in range(len(DT[0]))]
                for i in range(len(DT))
            ]
        print(DT)
        evalues, evectors = np.linalg.eig(DT)
        print("e-values:", evalues)
        print("e-vectors:", evectors)
        principal_eval = evalues[0]
        mean_sec_eval = (sum(evalues - principal_eval)) / 2
        if np.abs(evectors[2][1]) > np.abs(evectors[2][0]):
            principal_eval = evalues[1]
            mean_sec_eval = (sum(evalues - principal_eval)) / 2
            if np.abs(evectors[2][2]) > np.abs(evectors[2][1]):
                principal_eval = evalues[2]
                mean_sec_eval = (sum(evalues - principal_eval)) / 2
        else:
            if np.abs(evectors[2][2]) > np.abs(evectors[2][0]):
                principal_eval = evalues[2]
                mean_sec_eval = (sum(evalues - principal_eval)) / 2
        D_1.append(principal_eval)
        D_23.append(mean_sec_eval)
        print(t)
    for t in T:
        Phis.append(ComputePhi(t, 1000))
    plt.scatter(Phis, D_1)
    plt.scatter(Phis, D_23)
```

this is the .pyx file for `Fibril(...)` :

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def Fibril(np.float64_t x, np.float64_t y, np.float64_t L_0) -> np.float64_t:
    cdef np.float64_t argx = 2 * np.pi * x / L_0
    cdef np.float64_t argy = 2 * np.pi * y / L_0
    cdef np.float64_t term1 = np.cos(argx)
    cdef np.float64_t term2 = (81 / 320) * (term1**2)
    cdef np.float64_t term3 = (1 / 15) * (term1**3)
    cdef np.float64_t term4 = (3 / 320) * (term1**4)
    cdef np.float64_t term5 = np.cos(argy)
    cdef np.float64_t term6 = (81 / 320) * (term5**2)
    cdef np.float64_t term7 = (1 / 15) * (term5**3)
    cdef np.float64_t term8 = (3 / 320) * (term5**4)
    return term1 - term2 + term3 - term4 + term5 - term6 + term7 - term8
```

this is the .pyx file for `GetIntersect(...)` :

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from cython.cimports.libc.stdlib import free
import Fibril
import copy

def BorderEq(tuple[np.float64_t,np.float64_t] coordinates, np.float64_t L_0, np.float64_t T) -> np.float64_t:
    return Fibril.Fibril(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], L_0) - T

def GetIntersect(
    tuple[np.float64_t, np.float64_t, np.float64_t] coordinates, tuple[np.float64_t, np.float64_t, np.float64_t] oldcoord, double m, double q, double T, double L_0
) -> tuple[np.float64_t, np.float64_t]:  # gives intersection point on xy plane
    cdef double precision = 1e-21
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] x_range = np.linspace(oldcoord[0], coordinates[0], 100)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] y_range = np.linspace(oldcoord[1], coordinates[1], 100)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] borderpoints
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] distances
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] point_distances
    while not borderpoints.tolist():
        for x in x_range:
            for y in y_range:
                if 0 < BorderEq([x, y], L_0, T) < precision:
                    borderpoints = np.append(borderpoints, np.array([[x, y]]), axis=0)
        precision = precision * 100
    distances = np.empty(0, dtype=np.float64)
    for point in borderpoints:
        point_distances = np.empty(0, dtype=np.float64)
        for x in x_range:
            distance = np.sqrt((point[0]-x)**2 + (point[1]-(m*x+q))**2)
            point_distances = np.append(point_distances, distance)
        distances = np.append(distances, np.min(point_distances))
    nearest_point_index = np.argmin(distances)
    nearest_point = copy.copy(borderpoints[nearest_point_index])
    return nearest_point[0], nearest_point[1]
```

I have tried deallocating memory in the .pyx files (tried bot del and Pymem) but they would not compile afterwards